# Detect if a port is open on a remote machine using chrome apps socket api

Tags: sockets, google-chrome, google-chrome-app

I am trying to check whether a particular port is open on a remote machine port is open using chrome socket api in a chrome app.

I am doing something like this

```
socket.create("tcp", {}, function(r) {
  socket.connect(r.socketId, "google.com", 8000, function(e){
     console.log(e)
  });
});
```

The console.log callback gets called after about 60 seconds. Is there any faster alternative way for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trick was to call socket.timeout to some acceptable value. Most of the time socket.connect callback gets called instantaneously with value of 'e' as true or false depending on whether server accepted or rejected. Otherwise socket.timeout will invoke false.